# Display property for GetDocumentByElementId returns Null and Related Notification doesn't show

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngrx

There are two issues here. I have a notification service that functions perfectly however, I have set it's display property using Input from the store so that when the notification doesn't have any attributes the empty div doesn't take up space: 
currently It looks like this:

```
  @Input() type: any;
  @Input() message: any;
  @Input() timeout: any;
  @Input() display: any;


  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (document.getElementById("notification")) {
      document.getElementById("notification").style.display = this.display;
    }

  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="shared-notification" id="notificaiton">
    <alert [type]="type" [dismissOnTimeout]="timeout" [dismissible]="true">
        {{ message }}
    </alert>
</div>
```

However this doesn't work and the error it throws is

```
Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

I don't see why it's throwing this error as the component should already have been initialized.

Second problem is that I am trying to display the Notification inside a modal when an error is caught however, the notification is populated (I use ngrx dev tools to check the state and the store is updated when the error occurs) but the view doesn't update until I close and reopen the modal. 
The notification is represented by the parent selector being inserted into the modals parent's html as such:

```
<!-- there's a lot of html so I've just put a part of it here -->
<!-- Modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body no-padding bg-color-white">
    <Selector-that-works >
    </Selector-that-works>

    <!-- Step 2 Search Form -->
    <Second-Selector-That-Works>
    <Second-Selector-That-Works>

    <!-- Step 3: Confirmatione -->
    <This-One-Works-Too>
    </This-One-Works-Too>
  </div>
  <!-- error should show where selector is below but is delayed until Modal reOpens -->
  <notification-container></notification-container>
</ng-template>
```

I believe these two problems are related as both of them have to do with updating the view of the modal but neither seems to be working correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the spelling error

**id="notificaiton"** to **id="notificaton"**